# TortoiseGit 1.8 doesn't ask for credentials

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I just updated TortoiseGit to 1.8 and since then it's impossible to push or pull from the server. Before they asked to enter my password but they don't do it anymore. Instead they tell me :

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (1326 ms @ 2013-01-29
>   10:34:32)

I did not change anything in my settings, I use a ssh Url as remote origin (Vincent@example.com/git/...)

I'm in windows 8.

Comment: Same problem for me since I updated.

Comment: Just to be clear, if I push with Git Bash, it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but it's now resolved in version 1.8.1.
More info on the issue here: https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1617

Get the new fixed version 1.8.1 here: https://tortoisegit.org/download/

Answer (score 4):

I changed from TortoiseGitPLink.exe to TortoisePLink.exe in

Settings > Network > SSH > SSH Client
Then I got the password dialog.

It might be some incompability with TortoiseGitPLink.exe

The changelog says:

...

Renamed: TortoisePLink.exe to TortoiseGitPLink.exe (TortoisePLink.exe is still shipped for compatibility reasons)

...

Answer (score 2):

The TortoiseGit update might have messed up the application's path to TortoisePLink.exe.
[Revise your settings under](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/FAQ#How_to_make_TortoiseGit_use_OpenSSH_or_plink?) Settings > `Network` > `SSH` > `SSH Client`

Comment: Like Lars J mentioned, I changed the path to TortoisePLink.exe, because TortoiseGitPLink.exe produced the error that you described.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it as follows:

1) I changed the SSH client of TortoiseGit to Git\bin\ssh.exe

2) connected using ssh.exe to the remote server: ssh.exe username@address -p port_number

3) A message saying that the authenticity of host can't be established and whether I want to continue connecting appeared, so I typed "yes".

After this TortoiseGit started working for me.